# FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber not working properly - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

`await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` is not working properly in a sense that code after `await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` is running before successful execution of it. `await` is not really doing its job.

To make the understanding of the problem easy, I'm not gonna share all the code, just sharing the relevant code.
I have a **view** named `CustRegView` where I take a phone number form the user and send it to **ViewModel** named  `CustRegViewModel` to authenticate which is supposed to return true or false base on it's authentication.

Below is the how the **view** looks like

```
class CustRegView extends StatelessWidget{
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BaseView<CustRegViewModel>( 
          builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
    
    ...<some code>
    
    TextFeild( controller: _controller, ...<some code> )

    ...<some code>
    
    FlatButton (
        onPressed: () async {
            var registerSuccess = await model.register( _controller.text, context);
                                
            if (registerSuccess) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'newScreen');
            } else {
                UIHelper().showErrorButtomSheet(context, model.errorMessage);
            }
    )
}
```

Below is now **Viewmodel** looks like

```
class CustRegViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
    
    final AuthService _authService = locator<AuthService>();
    final DialogService _dialogService = locator<DialogService>();
    dynamic newUserResult;    <----  It will hold the authentication result value. IT'S VALUE SHOULD CHANGE FROM INSIDE "codeSent" FUNCTION OR "verificationCompleted" FUNCTION BUT IT IS NOT CHANGING

    Future<bool> register(String phoneNo, BuildContext context) async {
        print("Register function of viewModel is reached");
        setState(ViewState.Busy);
    
        await verifyPhone;

        if(newUserResult  !=  null){ 
            print("Returning true" )
            return true; 
        } else {    
            print("Returning false")
            return false;
        }
    }

    Future<void> verifyPhone(phoneNo) async {

        String smsCode;
        Future<String> getOTPresult() async { ...<some code> }

            print("VerifyFunction  is reached");
      
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber: updatedPhoneNo,
                    timeout: Duration(seconds: 50),
            verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCred) async {...... <some code>
                    verificationFailed: (AuthException authException) {...... <some code>
                    codeSent: (String verID, [int forceCodeResend]) async {
          
                        print(" --------------> Code sent reached. Will update newUserResult on success ");
                var OTPDialogResult = await getOTPresult();
                AuthCredential authCred = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential( verificationId: verID, smsCode: OTPDialogResult);            
                newUserResult =  AuthService().signInWithPhoneNumber(authCred);
                     },
                    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verID) {...

            ).catchError((error) {...... <some code>
      
            print( "Automatically returning null");

    }
}
```

Here, desired output should be something like this on  Console

```
Register function of viewModel is reached
VerifyFunction  is reached
--------------> Code sent reached. Will update newUserResult on success 
Returning true
```

While reaching CustRegViewModel register function I'm getting output like this, code sent is reaching after returning false

```
Register function of viewModel is reached
VerifyFunction  is reached
Automatically returning null
Returning false

--------------> Code sent reached. Will update newUserResult on success
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've actually solved the problem by simply using the `completer`. Now function won't return null automatically. `Completer` waits for the entire execution of `verifyPhoneNumber` method and return `true` or `false` based on desired result. I used it like this.

```
  Future<bool> verifyPhone(phoneNo) async {

    var completer = Completer<bool>();

            await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber: updatedPhoneNo,
                    timeout: Duration(seconds: 50),
                    verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCred) async {
                                ....<some code>
                               
                                completer.complete(true);

                     }
                    verificationFailed: (AuthException authException) {...... <some code>
                    codeSent: (String verID, [int forceCodeResend]) async {...... <some code>
                    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verID) {...
             ).catchError((error) {...... <some code>
       
      return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: This worked I was able to achieve the desired behaviour with this.