# Flutter FireBase - How can you asynchronously await verifyPhoneNumber?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, mobile-development

I'm trying to implement phone authentication in my Flutter application using  `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber` but do not know how to await it in an async function, so that the asynchronous `codeSent` parameter completes before moving on.

For example, with the following code:

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) {},
                verificationFailed: (error) {},
                codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) async {
                  await Future.delayed(
                    Duration(seconds: 2),
                  );
                },
                codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
              );
              print('COMPLETED');
            },
            child: Text('Verify'),
          ),
```

I want the `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2))` to complete before the print statement. Is there any way of implementing this functionality? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber not working properly - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493021/firebaseauth-instance-verifyphonenumber-not-working-properly-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is for `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2))` to be completed before the print statement, then call the print statement inside the `codeSent` method. Like this

```
codeSent: (String verificationId, [int? forceResendingToken]) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('COMPLETED');
},
```

Comment: I should've made clearer that the delayed future and print statement are just examples. In reality there's considerable async logic in the codeSent function, and the print statement would be statements dependent on the logic inside codeSent.

Comment: You can post the full code with the actual print statement so I can fully understand why my solution won't work, and customise it for you. BTW, I presently use firebase flutter phone auth and I implemented similar to my answer.